# how to extract listed names (placenames) from a text?

Tags: r, list, compare, geocoding, text-mining

I would like to extract placenames from a text and geolocate them on a map - automatically with R. The first step would be to extract the placenames.

I downloaded a list of placenames (from [geonames](http://download.geonames.org/export/dump/)); but how do I match the words from the geonames-placename-list within the text?

The possibility with `intersect()` does work only, when I convert the text to a vector - and therefore need to split the text into words, which causes the match-operator to only find one-word-placenames like "berlin" but not "new york" etc.

Does a function to compare a list with text (as string) exist?

MWE:

```
list = c("Wien", "London", "New York")
text = "Er sah den Stadtplan von Wien in New York."
words = unlist(strsplit(text, "\\W"))
intersect(list, words)
```

results in only:

```
> [1] "Wien"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you could use something like that

```
library(stringr)
    list = c("Wien", "London", "New York")
    text = "Er sah den Stadtplan von Wien in New York."
    words=as.character()

    for (i in 1:length(list)){

        if (is.na(str_extract(text,list[i]))) next

        x<-str_extract(text,list[i])
        words<-c(words,x)
    }


    > words
    [1] "Wien"     "New York"
```

Comment: thanks!
actually, the answer you helped me with was the command `str_extract()`. my main point was in getting the output from `unlist(str_extract_all(text,list))` - thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Depending on complexity you could also use (be careful with spaces)

```
list = c("Wien", "London", "NewYork")
text = "Er sah den Stadtplan von Wien in NewYork."
words = unlist(strsplit(text, "\\W"))
list[list %in% words]
```

`"Wien" "NewYork"`